# What device do I need for a live video chat?

Tags: webcam

Should I prepare a webcam and a headset?

I went to the Logitech website and found out that their [webcam](http://www.logitech.com/en-hk/webcam-communications/webcams/devices/7079) can receive and emit sound. Maybe I misinterpreted it. Then do I still need a headset?

If we need both webcam and headset, how should they be connected?

And the above webcam provide HD720 video, but in the spec it said I need at least 1 Mbps upload speed. However, I am using ADSL for internet and have a unbalanced download and upload speed. My download speed is okay, but I only have 64 kbps upload. Is this webcam not suitable for me?

Comment: If you like. To the computer. I'm sure the software can do something about it, as long as you don't *mind* not doing 720p.

Comment: The webcam doesn't have speakers, so you'll need computer speakers too.

Comment: @AndrejaKo I don't understand. The link said the webcam has some technology with the sound. Does it mean it receive sound, as you said webcam doesn't have speaker?

Comment: @gunbuster363 If you go to the specifications page, you'll see that the webcam has a microphone which uses their whateverIt'snameIs proprietary technology which is supposed to make it sound better. Key word is only microphone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Should I prepare a webcam and a headset?**

I would. A headset removes the possibility of horrible feedback and echo rendering you unintelligible. However, as AndrejaKo comments, good quality webcams with integrated microphones  and speakers should work fine in modern PCs.

> **If we need both webcam and headset, how should they be connected?**

Plug the webcam into a free USB port on your computer

Plug the headset into the appropriate audio jacks at the rear or front of your computer

[image]

At the rear a PC usually has several sockets with PC-99 colour-coding

```
Orange  TRS 3.5 mm  Output, subwoofer
Blue    TRS 3.5 mm  Input, line level
Pink    TS  3.5 mm  microphone input
Lime    TRS 3.5 mm  Output, front channels
Brown   TRS 3.5 mm  Output, 'Right-to-left speaker'
Gold    TRS 3.5 mm  MIDI/game
```

[image]

At the front is often a TRS 3.5 mm headphone socket and an adjacent TS 3.5 mm microphone socket.

[image]

> **webcam … HD720 … need … 1mbps … ADSL … 64 kbps … Is this webcam not suitable for me?**

Yes, if it can also be used at a much lower resolution and fewer frames per second.

Comment: The audio port already have a speaker istalled. Can I plug it to the speaker?

Comment: @gunbuster363: Many headsets nowdays comes with USB connection instead of jack, so you can use USB instead. If you have a laptop with Bluetooth, that is also an option. Many handsfree sets for mobile phones use Bluetooth.

Comment: @gunbuster363: Some desktop speakers have a headphone socket, you could use that but you'd have to plug the microphone in to a separate microphone socket and this usually isn't practical. You shouldn't plug headphones into a socket designed for a speaker because the output levels are very different.

Comment: Most operating systems and sound cards today are capable of preventing feedback in software. In fact, I haven't seen a computer with feedback problems in several years, so using speakers and the microphone integrated in camera should be fine.